# Truncate text using ellipsis also truncates the tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am truncating text using ellipsis and showing the entire text on the tooltip. If the text overflows then only the tool tip is shown.
The tooltip looks fine in Chrome, but not in IE and Firefox. In IE, the tooltip text is also truncated and in firefox, the tooltip itself is cut.

```
<div class="card">
    <p>From:</p>
    <p> Dark Angel </p>
    <p class="ellipsis"> QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQAAAAAA
        New york, US<p>        
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
    height:416px;
    width:280px;
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('p.ellipsis').bind('mouseenter', function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth && !$this.attr('title'))
        $this.attr('title', $this.text());
```

Comment: Would it be nice if you have maximum length limit for your string and then if goes beyond that then clip it?

Comment: How are you testing? [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncxsf/3/) works fine in all the latest browsers under Windows 7.

Comment: I am testing IE10 , windows 8 and it doesnt work in IE10. The title text is also truncated with ellipsis.. I want the entire text to be shown in the title.

Comment: Oh boy, you're right. It shows completely in IE10 under Windows 7, but is truncated in IE10 under Windows 8. So, an OS issue rather than a browser issue. I'm afraid you may not have much chance of getting it working.

Comment: May be worth looking at https://caniuse.com/#search=ellipsis for this.. Perhaps see if things like bootstrap have blog discussing shims/polyfills for this type of thing.

Comment: The solution I've given below will work regardless of OS and browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the element a different class name and then use Javascript to update it, setting the relevant `ellipsis` class name, as well as capturing the text at that time and storing it as a data attribute of the element, so you can access it later.

Note that I changed the `<p>` tag to have the class name `pre-ellipsis`...

```js
// add a data-title attribute with the original text, then modify the class list
// to remove pre-ellipsis and add ellipsis

$("p.pre-ellipsis").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data("title", $this.text());
    $this.removeClass("pre-ellipsis").addClass("ellipsis");
});

// your original code, but modified to get the tooltip text from the data attribute
$("p.ellipsis").on("mouseenter", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth && !$this.attr('title')) {
        $this.attr('title', $this.data("title"));
    }
});
```

```css
.card {
    height:416px;
    width:280px;
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
<p>From:</p>
<p> Dark Angel </p>
<p class="pre-ellipsis"> QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQAAAAAA
New york, US<p>        
<div>
```